# Browser visual bug

Tags: noobs, web-browsers

I just got my Raspberry Pi 4 model B and installed and updated NOOBS.

The browser has a visual bug which looks like this:

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Set up with what? Add more information such as OS + version to your question. And is your system fully  updated?

Comment: @Dirk I've updated the question with the requested information.

Comment: NOOBS is no longer recommended. Flash Raspberry Pi OS direct to your sd card with Pi Imager. https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/

Comment: @CoderMike Thank you, that solved the problem.

Comment: @CoderMike That shouldn't have this side effect, though. That was rather some incorrect screen size configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NOOBS is no longer recommended.

Flash Raspberry Pi OS direct to your sd card with Pi Imager.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/